# Flex RTMP client

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder, rtmp

I'm trying to write an rtmp client with flex. The problem is that I have no idea where to start. Could someone please answer how I would go about doing this, or point me to a site that does? Thanks. I don't even know what classes to use and such.

Comment: I voted to close as this is an overly broad question along the lines of "Do my wor for me."  What have you tried?  Where have you run into problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to write your own RTMP client because Flash already implements a RTMP client called [`NetConnection`](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/NetConnection.html).

To create a basic connection you could do the following:

```
var nc:NetConnection = new NetConnection();
nc.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, onNetStatus);
nc.connect('rtmp://127.0.0.1/application');

function onNetStatus(e:NetStatusEvent):void
{
    switch (e.info.code)
    {
        case 'NetConnection.Connect.Success':
            // Connection with the RTMP server has been established
            break;

       case '...':
          ...
    }
}
```

The code 'NetConnection.Connect.Success' you see is one of the codes the server returns, have a look [over here](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/events/NetStatusEvent.html#info) for an overview of all the codes.

You should probably read up on the documentation first and then come back with a more precise question.

Answer (score 3):

See Wiki [Real Time Messaging Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Time_Messaging_Protocol) as a starting point

and there are few sample clients

[JUV RTMP Client](http://www.smaxe.com/juvclient.jsf)

[php-rtmp-client](http://code.google.com/p/php-rtmp-client/)

hopes that works