# Playing RTP stream in flex

Tags: apache-flex, audio-streaming, rtp, codec

**I am trying to play the RTP playload in flex but no success. Can some enlighten me how to achieve this without using RTMP Server as middle ware.**

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6011684/flex-rtmp-client

Comment: The Question is  alike but i guess no adequate solution is supplied. I don't want my Air application to be dependent on any RTMP server. I guess i have to build one in flex and stream in incoming RTP packets back to NetStream. Does any open source implementation exists for RTMP server in AS3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that without using an RTMP server. The NetConnection class you find in Flex can send and receive RTMP streams, and those streams can have the same payload you find in RTP packets. Although, to unpack RTP packets and create RTMP packets you need an RTMP server like Wowza Media Server, or something alike.

Comment: I don't want my Air application to be dependent on any RTMP server. I guess i have to build one in flex and stream in incoming RTP packets back to NetStream. Does any open source implementation exists for RTMP server in AS3?

Answer (score 0):

There are several open source media servers you can use:

- [Red5](http://www.red5.org/)
- [Wowza](http://www.wowza.com/)
- [RTMPD](http://www.rtmpd.com/)

Any of these would suit your purpose. Flex makes the client side pretty trivial too.

Comment: I agree but i want to build the process in flex so that the application is not dependent on any server process for processing RTP packets. Do you have any experience is porting the RTMPD lib with flash++. The real problem is the Network and Sound LIBS are not part of the GCC and depends on the target and i want a single compiled lib for easy access across platforms. I will dive into the c++ code and try making changes to the Network Process but this will be trivial. Lets hope for the best.

Comment: So you want server-side flex? I guess I'm puzzled as to your goal. The presence of an RTMP stream implies a server process.. somewhere.

Comment: Yes and why not flex has the capabilities for ServerSocket this could be my RTMP Server within my Air application and facilitate the web hosted SWF for VOIP calls.

Comment: I am currently looking at hxis implementation for haxe RTMP Server; i guess this will be a good candidate to port to flex as they can be compiled for as3 target instead of neko.

Comment: It sounds like you are hoping to write  VOIP solution that doesn't need a central server. Maybe you can skip the NetStream portion and go straight to a socket-socket interface with something like https://github.com/simb/FlashSocket.IO#readme.

Comment: OTOH having a central server makes things like finding connections and managing them much easier.